# PHP nested array into HTML list

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, html-lists

Trying to get to grips with PHP, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

I want to take this array:

```
$things = array('vehicle' => array('car' => array('hatchback', 'saloon'),'van','lorry'),
                'person' => array('male', 'female'),
                'matter' => array('solid', 'liquid', 'gas'),
            );
```

and turn it into this into something like this in HTML:

- Vehicle

  - Car

    - Hatchback
    - Saloon
  - Van
  - Lorry
- Person

  - Male
  - Female
- Matter

  - Solid
  - Liquid
  - Gas

Tried a number of solutions from searching, but cannot get anything to work at all.

Comment: Where are the "solutions" you tried? What did "not work"?

Comment: use recursion and loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional array to HTML unordered list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865864/multidimensional-array-to-html-unordered-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Recursion. Below is a recursive function that calls itself if the value of the array key is also an array.

```
function printArrayList($array)
{
    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            echo "<li>" . $k . "</li>";
            printArrayList($v);
            continue;
        }

        echo "<li>" . $v . "</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: I'll try my best to implement it. Thank you for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Update: This worked straight away, thank you so much!

Comment: This should also work for arrays that contain both arrays and static values. i.e. `array("foo"=>array("a","b"),"bar","baz");`

Comment: That's great! Thanks again. I can't upvote because my reputation is still low, but I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<?php
function ToUl($input){
   echo "<ul>";

   $oldvalue = null;
   foreach($input as $value){
     if($oldvalue != null && !is_array($value))
        echo "</li>";
     if(is_array($value)){
        ToUl($value);
     }else
        echo "<li>" + $value;
      $oldvalue = $value;
    }

    if($oldvalue != null)
      echo "</li>";

   echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Code source: [Multidimensional array to HTML unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865996/3189338)